# Having tests to wait for a performSelector to fire

Tags: ios, macos, xctest, nsrunloop, performselector

So I'm writing tests for this operation where I do something and if it fails we lazily try to perform this operation again using a `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, now I would like to wait for my *runloop* in the tests to fire this performSelector before tearing down the tests. This essentially boils down to keeping the runloop up for some more time.

I've found

> [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:delta]];

to be useful and it works fine.

Is there a better way to do this??

Comment: XCTest now supports asynchronous testing. Have a look at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I missed this but as [Abizern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41116/abizern) commented, Xcode6 introduces asynchronous testing. Here is the right way to do [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/). Scroll down to the Asynchronous testing section and this should suffice.